# Dynamically add/remove rows in Razor page table and then save the changes to a database using EF Core

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, bootstrap-4, entity-framework-core

I am having trouble dynamically adding and removing rows of a table. My data model is as follows:

I have a class called `Tool`, which can have a number of options `ToolRunOptions`.

```
public class Tool : BaseTable
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = String.Empty; 
    [Display(Name = "Key Name")]
    public string KeyName { get; set; } = String.Empty; //what's used to indicate which tool to run
    public string Description { get; set; } = null!;
    [Display(Name = "Tool Type")]
    public ToolType ToolType { get; set; } //The type of tool i.e. Recon
    [Display (Name = "Image Link")]
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; } = null!; //sets an image for the tool
    public virtual List<TargetType> AllowedTargets { get; set; } = new List<TargetType>(); //Target types which can be passed to the tool
    public virtual List<ToolRunOptions> ToolRunOptions { get; set; } = new List<ToolRunOptions>(); //A list of options that can be specified for a tool
    public List<string> Targets = new List<string>();
}

public enum ToolType
{
    [Display(Name = "x")]
    Recon,
    [Display(Name = "y")]
    Monitoring,
    [Display(Name = "z")]
    VulnScanner
        
}

// tool run options class
public class ToolRunOptions : BaseTable
{
    public Tool Tool { get; set; } = new Tool();
    public string RunOptionName { get; set; } = String.Empty;
    public string RunOptionCommand { get; set; } = String.Empty;
}
```

My controller looks like this:

```
public class EditModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly DataContext _context;

    public EditModel(DataContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public Tool Tool { get; set; }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(Guid? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        Tool = await _context.Tools.Include(x => x.ToolRunOptions).FirstOrDefaultAsync(t => t.Id == id);

        if (Tool == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        //Add a place holder for a new tool run option if there are no tool options related to this tool
        if (Tool.ToolRunOptions.Count < 1)
        {
            var toolOptionPlaceholder = new ToolRunOptions()
            {
                Id = new Guid(),
                Tool = this.Tool,
                RunOptionName = "Insert name here",
                RunOptionCommand = "Insert run command",
                New = true
            };

            Tool.ToolRunOptions.Add(toolOptionPlaceholder);
        }

        return Page();
    }

    //On post for general tool options like name and description etc
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        // we want to update the tool options here
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }

        _context.Attach(Tool).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!ToolExists(Tool.Id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
    }

    // on post method for the tool options
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostOptionsAsync()
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }

        // changes the state of the tool to modified
        // _context.Attach(Tool).State = EntityState.Modified;

        foreach (var option in Tool.ToolRunOptions)
        {
            if (option.New)
            {
                // adds an option to the database
                _context.Add(option);
            }
            else
            {
                _context.Attach(option).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }

            option.New = false;
        }

        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
    }

    private bool ToolExists(Guid id)
    {
        return _context.Tools.Any(e => e.Id == id);
    }

    private bool ToolRunOptionsExists(Guid id)
    {
        return _context.ToolRunOptions.Any(tro => tro.Id == id);
    }
}
```

And finally my razor page looks like this.. I am trying using tab panes to edit both the tool and the tool run options in one page.

```
@page
@model AttackSurfaceReview.Pages.Tools.EditModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit";
    Layout = "~/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div class="row">
    <h1><img src=@Model.Tool.ImageUrl style="float:left;width:150px;height:113px; margin-right:10px;">Edit @Model.Tool.Name </h1>
</div>
<a href="./Index">Back to Tools</a>
<div class="row">
    <a href="/Tools/Delete/?id=@Model.Tool.Id" class="btn col-md-4 btn-danger" style="margin-left: 10px;">Delete Tool</a>
</div>

<hr />
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist" style="margin-bottom:10px">
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <button class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#home" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">General Settings</button>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <button class="nav-link" id="options-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#options" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="options" aria-selected="false">Tool Options</button>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <button class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#contact" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Targets</button>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
        <form method="post">

            <h3>Tool Settings</h3>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Tool.Id" />
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label asp-for="Tool.Name" class="control-label"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Tool.Name" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Tool.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class=col-md-6>
                        <label asp-for="Tool.KeyName" class="control-label"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Tool.KeyName" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Tool.KeyName" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label asp-for="Tool.Description" class="control-label"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Tool.Description" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Tool.Description" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label asp-for="Tool.ToolType" class="control-label"></label>
                        <select id="ToolTypeSelect" class="form-control" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<AttackSurfaceReview.ASRData.Model.ToolType>()"></select>
                        <span asp-validation-for="Tool.ToolType" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <label asp-for="Tool.ImageUrl" class="control-label"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Tool.ImageUrl" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Tool.ImageUrl" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <input style="margin-bottom: 10px;" type="submit" value="Save" class="btn col-md-4 btn-primary" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <!--Tool Options section for adding and removing tool options-->
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="options" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="options-tab">
        <h3>Tool Options</h3>
        <form method="post">
            <div class="d-flex gap-2 mb-3">
                @*                <button class="btn btn-primary" asp-page-handler="options" id="saveOptions" type="button" value="Save"><i class="bi bi-save"></i></button>
                <button class="btn btn-success" asp-page-handler="new" id="AddOption" type="submit"><i class="bi bi-file-earmark-plus-fill"></i></button>*@
                <button class="btn btn-primary" id="saveOptions" type="button" value="Save" onclick="addRow()"><i class="bi bi-save"></i></button>
                <button class="btn btn-success" id="AddOption" type="submit" onclick="saveOption()"><i class="bi bi-file-earmark-plus-fill"></i></button>
            </div>
            <table id="optionTable" class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Tool.ToolRunOptions[0].RunOptionName)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Tool.ToolRunOptions[0].RunOptionCommand)
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (var option in Model.Tool.ToolRunOptions)
                    {
                        <input asp-for="@option.Id" id="OptionId" class="d-none" />
                        <tr>
                            <td id="NameColumn" class="form-group">
                                <div class="editdiv" contenteditable="true">@option.RunOptionName</div>
                                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@option.RunOptionName" />
                            </td>
                            <td id="CommandColumn" class="form-group">
                                <div class="editdiv" contenteditable="true">@option.RunOptionCommand</div>
                                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@option.RunOptionCommand" class="form-control" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <button class="btn btn-danger" onClick"="deletRow(this)"><i class="bi bi-trash3-fill"></i></button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">.dsfsadfsdaf..</div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{
        await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");
    }

    <script>
        function addRow() {
            var table = document.getElementById("optionTable");
            var row = table.insertRow(table.rows.length - 1);
            row.innerHTML = `<td><input name="ToolRunOptions[${table.rows.length - 2}].OptionName" class="form-control" /></td>
                                     <td><input name="ToolRunOptions[${table.rows.length - 2}].OptionCommand" class="form-control" /></td>
                                     <td><button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" onclick="deleteRow(this)">Delete</button></td>`;
        }

        function deleteRow(button) {
            var row = button.parentNode.parentNode;
            row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
        }

    </script>
}
```

For some reason when I try and add a row using the add button it resets all the values of my Tool class. It's like the program creates a new tool when adding a row to the table.

I also am really unsure on the best way to do this and save any changes on the options tab pane.

Comment: Do you mean when you click `<button class="btn btn-primary" id="saveOptions" type="button" value="Save" onclick="addRow()"><i class="bi bi-save"></i></button>` button, It will resets all the values of Tool class? But I try your code and when i click this button, It just add a row for user to input `RunOptionName` and `RunOptionCommand` , the value of tool class will not be resets.. Can you provide a gif to show what's going on in your project?

Comment: @XinranShen yes this is correct